# Save Record function does not execute in Record Level Client Script

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to execute a simple function that logs the record type whenever an employee record is saved.

```
function saveRecordRec(){
    var stType = nlapiGetRecordType();
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Record type of current record', stType);
    return true;
}
```

I have a pageInit function not listed here, running in this same script file. This function is running as intended, so I am sure I have the correct script loaded into Netsuite. I also have checked and it appears [I have the Scripts form filled in correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X67Wv.jpg) However, [nothing displays in my Execution Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NftmM.jpg) even after I have executed the rest of my scripts on an employee record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I waited an extended amount of time (about an hour) and a log was finally recorded. I did not change anything in Netsuite or in my script. I simply had to wait.
[Here is the intended result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UGnh.jpg)

It was supposedly logged more than an hour ago and had not displayed until 11:18am today.

Answer (score 0):

This is because client scripts run in the browser unless running in a web context as a "Scriptable Cart and Checkout" script.